# Set cookie and redirect if cookie set based on url

Tags: php, cookies, woocommerce

I am running woocommerce/wordpress and noticed customers refreshing the thankyou page cause google analytics to record multiple transactions.

The url they visit is: /checkout/order-received/24420/?key=wc_order_a5m1jzQDJLjjr

I figure i need to Set a cookie using that order number. If cookie exists then redirect before analytics code runs. Thus preventing reloads of thank you page.. (i hope)

I don't know who to extract the number 24420 from the url and set a cookie. Redirecting on Cookie i can figure out.

thanks

/J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the **Order ID**

```
$order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] );
```

I would suggest to use a session instead of cookie so you can do something like

```
if(isset($_SESSION['order_'.$order_id])) {
    header("Location: /where-you-want");
    die;
} else {
    $_SESSION['order_'.$order_id] = 1;
}
```

Please note that both Session and Cookies need to be set **before any other output on the page**, so be sure that the code you're running is executed before any HTML is printed.

Comment: No problem, if the answer solved your issue, please mark it as the accepted answer so future readers can quickly find the solution too